# How accept/refuse a drop with angular

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop

Question abour cdk package of angular :
I would like to drag and drop the red div "drag me" (see below) into the blue drop area, only if a drop condition is true.

[image]

My drag works fine (so the cdk library is properly loaded) but my drop doesn't work, my enterPredicate() method is never called. Any idea ? ([link cdk](https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/api#CdkDropList))

app.component.html

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CdkDragEnd, CdkDragStart, CdkDragMove, CdkDragDrop, moveItemInArray, CdkDrag, CdkDropList } from '@angular/cdk/drag-drop';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'Tour of heroes';
  state = '';
  position = '';

  dragStarted(event: CdkDragStart) {
    this.state = 'dragStarted';
  }

  dragEnded(event: CdkDragEnd) {
    this.state = 'dragEnded';
  }

  dragMoved(event: CdkDragMove) {
    this.position = `> Position X: ${event.pointerPosition.x} - Y: ${event.pointerPosition.y}`;
  }

  dropped(event: CdkDragDrop<string[]>) {
    console.log("dropped");
  }

  enterPredicate(drag?: CdkDrag, drop?: CdkDropList) {

    return false;
  };
}
```

app.component.html

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>

<!--  ITEM TO BE DRAGGED -->
<div cdkDrag class="drag-box"
     (cdkDragStarted)="dragStarted($event)"
     (cdkDragEnded)="dragEnded($event)"
     (cdkDragMoved)="dragMoved($event)">
  drag me
</div>

<p>{{state}} {{position}}</p>

<!--   DROP  ZONE -->
<div cdkDropList
     (cdkDropListDropped)="dropped($event)"
     style="background-color:lightblue; width: 200px; height: 200px"
     [cdkDropListEnterPredicate]="enterPredicate(drag, cdkDropList)"
     >
  DROP   ZONE
</div>

<app-heroes></app-heroes>
<app-messages></app-messages>
```

I would like the drop to be executed only if enterPredicate() is true.

Comment: I didn't find what is wrong in my code, but a found another example which works fine : [link](https://github.com/angular/material2/commit/ce500dc09d1428737d7a1384d4aaa4392d5a83ea)

Comment: Old question, but in the html don't put a function call, just the function name: `[cdkDropListEnterPredicate]="enterPredicate"`. CdkDrag and CdkDropList args are passed automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you need the T in your function definition.

```
enterPredicate(drag?: CdkDrag<string>, drop?: CdkDropList<string[]>)
```

It didn't work for me until I added the types.